# Where i can find the nice dialog data preview in ADLA Tools?

Tags: azure-data-lake

I've installed VS 2015 sp3 + ADLA Tools 2.2.5000.0

When i click Cloud Explorer -> Select a U-SQL Table -> Preview By Running a Job, it runs a U-SQL job that pulls some data to a csv file and next i can preview the file.

But some people show the screen bellow at forums. Where i can find it in GUI? Maybe ADLA Tools installed incorrectly :). Or maybe these people have an access to a beta versions of ADLA Tools?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot is for a Local table.  You should be able to do the same for your Local tables.  Right-click a Local table and there will be a "Preview" option.

Comment: understood, thank you so much! i broke my head while trying to realize where people found the option (i use azure adla, not local).